# JPA/Hibernate: Using params as function params?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, parameters, jpql

```
return em.createQuery(
     "SELECT doc FROM TexyDoc doc 
       WHERE doc.origPath LIKE CONCAT('%', :1)")
    .setParameter(1, path)
```

leads to

```
QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found '1' near line 1, column 82 
[SELECT doc FROM cz.oz.web.model.TexyDoc doc 
   WHERE doc.origPath LIKE CONCAT('%', :1)]
```

Why? What should be the syntax like?

Comment: Why do the select? just 'from TexyDoc where origPath like ..' should do it..

Comment: Ha, damn thing was based on HQL but dropped that, ok.. you're right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the way you are doing the args. Do this instead:

```
LIKE CONCAT('%', :path)"
```

and then:

```
.setParameter("path", path);
```

more readable to have named params.